# How do true wireless earbuds perform inter-ear communication?

Tags: audio, bluetooth

What protocol, frequency band and messaging style is used by typical popular true wireless earbuds between the two ears? Is it another Bluetooth connection? Bluetooth LE, or something proprietary to the chipset?

In typical popular true wireless earbuds, I understand in stereo mode only one bud communicates with the source device, and relays audio data to the other earbud over a secondary connection. Is my understanding correct? How do they deal with the challenge of transmitting through the wearer's head (or around)?

Thanks in advance for any pointers to a technical description. If there is no commonality between different devices, feel free to describe the model for a particular popular device eg AirPods, Jabra 65t, etc or chipset manufacturer (Qualcomm, Realtek etc)

Comment: Some use magnetic induction: https://mindtribe.com/2017/06/here-one-teardown/ while I believe others use a passive Bluetooth snoop on the second earbud.

Comment: Why do you think there is communication between the earbuds? That seems redundant.

Comment: The earbuds have to know what each other is doing so they need to send messages between them to co-ordinate and synchronise

Comment: The claims about near field magnetic induction being used appear to be marketing lies, I've seen no evidence this is being used in bluetooth earbuds.

Comment: @tomr. This is almost its own question but **why can't / isn't this done through the (connection to the) actual device ?** I know many say the waves through your head are not harmful but that's actually still not proved and furthermore there are more and more wireless signals nowadays so until it's proven, one should try to minimize it *imo* and furthermore less signals are always a win, probably for battery life as well.

Comment: The method described in my answer below does minimise redundant communication.  It wouldn't be possible to do this through the host device because the host device needs to be unaware of the internal details of the audio sink. When it comes to the effect of non-ionising radiation on the body, scientific consensus is these fears are unfounded leaving this more a topic area relevant to conspiracy theorists.

Answer (score 11):

I can't stand not knowing how this works so I did some research by reading some patents - their language is intentionally vague in some areas, but I did discover some commonalities in what they considered to be current normal practice:

- It seems common in more recent true wireless earbuds for the "slave" earbud to receive its audio data not through the master re-transmitting to it, but by eavesdropping in on the bluetooth connection from the source to master.  This avoids the need for re-transmitting the data.  The slave listens on this connection but never replies; that is left to the master and the source device does not even need to know that there are two earbuds listening to it.

  - This approach seems more efficient and it seems like it would cut down on latency, yet true wireless earbuds continue to have significantly higher latency than other stereo bluetooth earbuds that are not true wireless.  I can speculate that additional latency still needs to be built in for them to be more tolerant to congestion throwing sync between the two earbuds out (for example, slave fails decoding a packet and needs it re-transmitted, so it must ask master to ask the source to re-transmit it, and this all is needed before the respective piece of audio is played).
- For synchronization and state information the two earbuds still need to communicate with each other as well.  I've seen this referred to as a "secondary" connection and as a "hybrid" connection (the source calling it a hybrid connection referred to the slave earbud's passive listening to the original connection a "secondary" connection).

  - Since Bluetooth is a secure encrypted protocol, the master will need to share the encryption keys it negotiated during connection over this secondary connection between the two earbuds, and that needs to also be a secure connection.
  - This connection between the two earbuds appears therefore to be another classic bluetooth connection.  This doesn't rule out some devices using more exotic methods of communicating with each other, but this would make sense given that both earbuds are already bluetooth devices.
- In online articles and product marketing information I've seen reference to some bluetooth devices that use "near field magnetic induction" to communication with each other.  As far as I can tell this is marketing lies.
- In any case, in a true wireless stereo pair the master is still doing more work than the slave requiring greater power use; many these days can swap master and slave without any interruption to the audio in order to drain battery more evenly, leading to greater battery life since your battery life of the whole pair is only as good as the master's remaining battery.

  (Update 2022) I believe this is now more commonplace than when I wrote this answer, and that you can determine if yours support this: if either earbud can be used on its own, without them appearing as two different Bluetooth devices when pairing.  This is a sign that your earbuds support automatically determining which one is master.

The whole concept of true wireless earbuds is so new that almost everything published about it is from 2016 or later, and the devices back in 2016 and 2017 were primitive by today's standards.  And, the makers of chipsets have an incentive not to share too much detail about their internal operation.

Comment: As consequences the master earbud exists, just microphone from one earbud i used during call in some products.

This is experience from my SoundCore Liberty Air 2. Even both earbuds have microphones, just master earbud is sending voice from microphone. So sound from right earbud mic (default primary) is used. Only when right earbud is turned off, then left one is master (and then left mic is used insted of right one).

Comment: The "near field magnetic induction" thing is almost certainly marketing lies, because the earbuds are too far apart when worn to have any significant near-field coupling between them except at very low frequencies, and they're too physically small to have any coupling except at fairly high frequencies.

Comment: The near field magnetic induction claims puzzle me.  Mostly it appears on off-brand stuff so it's easier to dismiss as marketing lies, except when it pops up in Jabra's official site for example [here](https://www.jabra.com.au/supportpages/jabra-elite-active-75t/100-99091001-40/faq/why-did-the-audio-pause-when-i-removed-one-of-my-earbuds). Could still be a falsehood. The other puzzling thing is, it would make more sense for it to just be a second classic bluetooth connection - the hardware's already there and the additional strain on battery would be minimal as it's not a constant stream.

Comment: The explanation for how NFMI works on that Jabra site is nonsensical, too.  Sounds like what they're actually describing is a feature that detects when an earbud is removed from your ear and lets the other ear keep playing, and the author of the documentation has wrongly been told this is because of NFMI. If NFMI was required for inter-bud communication, breaking that wouldn't allow that transition to happen.
Edit: nowhere else on Jabra's site do they claim the Active 75t uses NFMI. It's just incorrect documentation.

Comment: but i know there are earbuds that can be used individually - is there a master  as well when using both? Or don't even all true-wireless-earbuds necessarily inter-communicate? Did anyone ever disassemble different ones and shared his findings or is this mostly knowledge hidden in the companies internal engineering groups? Questions over questions lol, btw nice to hear there are others as well that aren't satisfied with the most vague answers ;)

Comment: Communication between the two buds is always going to be necessary for synchronisation at the very least, and they have to decide between each other which one is going to be the one that replies to the host, so as to appear to the host as a single device, so in that scenario I use master to refer to that one.  Whether a given product "swaps" masters on its own is up to the way it's implemented in that product.